# How to check if a value is a promise?

Tags: clojure

Having:

```
(def x (promise))
```

How can I check the the type of x is a promise?

Thanks

Comment: You can't util you create another abstraction over promise that has some info to tell whether it is promise or not

Comment: @Ankur Would `(defn promise? [x] (pos? (.indexOf (str (type x)) "clojure.core$promise")))` be laughable?

Comment: @A.Webb That would be no laughing matter: aside from needing a small fix in order to work, I would expect thugs coming by your code saying things like "That's a really nice function you have here. It'd be a shame if something were to...*happen* to it." And then the next release of Clojure would change the implementation detail you're depending on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd say you can't generally. Because promise is created as `reify` of several interfaces: `IDeref`, `IBlockingDeref`, `IPending`, `IFn`. But you can check whether value implements one of them: `clojure.lang.IPending`.

```
(defn promise? [v]
  (instance? clojure.lang.IPending p))
```

Or maybe even all:

```
(defn promise? [v]
  (every? #(instance? % v) 
         [clojure.lang.IPending 
          clojure.lang.IFn 
          clojure.lang.IBlockingDeref 
          clojure.lang.IDeref]))
```

Comment: With the former, (promise? (filter even? [1 2 3])) => true, so I'd definitely use the latter.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with

```
(defn promise? [p]
  (isa? (class p) clojure.lang.IPending))
```